# Justify conditional

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

If there is an interpretation $I$ in wich $A=\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ is true, then $(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ is not true ands is not false in $I$.

I need to justifiy this is false. So, if A is true for $I$ this means that every valuation on $I$ satisfies A. A little more formally, valuation $v$ satisfies $\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ iff $v$ satisfies $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ and every x-equivalent valuation $v'$  satisfies $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$. Therefore, it doesnt exists a valuation on $I$ in wich $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ is false, then $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ is true for $I$.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you did a fine job with the proof.

So the only suggestion I'll make is simply a matter of "parsing"/choice of words, not directly related to the "content" of the proof. I'll italicize the word choices, then follow each italicization with a suggested replacement, which you can "take or leave."

"...  [M]ore formally, valuation $v$ satisfies $\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ *iff* [if and only if] $v$ satisfies $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$, and every x-equivalent valuation $v'$  satisfies $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$. Therefore, *it doesn't exists* [there does not exist] a valuation on $I$ *in* [for?] which $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ is false, *then* [and hence it follows that] $P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ is true for $I$."

Comment: Thanks. And this is not mi native lang, usually i dont know what words to use.

Comment: You did quite well, better than many *native* English speakers! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice feedback! +1